# Redirect login url

Tags: plugins

I've got this user submitted post plugin I would like to customized.

Heres the code:

```
function usp_login_required_message() {

    $message  = '<p>'. esc_html__('Please', 'usp');
    $message .= ' <a href="'. wp_login_url() .'">'. esc_html__('log in', 'usp') .'</a> ';
    $message .= esc_html__('to submit content!', 'usp') .'</p>';

    $message = apply_filters('usp_require_login', $message);

    return $message;

}
```

What I want is when I click “log in” I want to go to `http://www.jajan.com/register` instead of `http://www.jajan.com/wp-login.php`.

How to do it?

Comment: And why do you need so?

Comment: I just need to change the wp-login,php to my own register link

Comment: I just need to change the link from wp-login.php to my own link for register

Comment: `usp_require_login` is totally unknown to me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing that.
This would be a hack.

There is no option inside WordPress to do so yet. That would be perfect.

I know there is a filter
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_url
but if this works for you let me know.

And there are plugins that use the `redirect` hook like [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/).
You can check the code.

They need to do several things so not super easy.

Comment: heres my post https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-user-submit-to-other-link/